# CPU high usage with no reason

Tags: cpu

I am experiencing high CPU usage and overheating with
 Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron-N5110 laptop, seemingly for no reason.

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz Cadencé à 2.30 GHz
- RAM: 4 GB
- Multimedia:

  - Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
  - NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller

Comment: If the CPU usage is high, then there has to be at least one program using it. What does `top` show?

Comment: Also, it seems that you have an dedicated graphics adapter which may also cause overheating. Are you sure it is the CPU and how do you know?

Comment: top - 13:32:39 up  2:54,  2 users,  load average: 0,15, 0,27, 0,52
Tasks: 176 total,   1 running, 175 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,8 us,  0,8 sy,  0,0 ni, 97,5 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   4049512 total,  1683728 used,  2365784 free,    98332 buffers
KiB Swap:  4097020 total,        0 used,  4097020 free.   996644 cached Mem

Comment: @Adaephon high temperature and noise.

Comment: From what I can see your PC is not doing anything of note at the moment (97,5 id(le)). Is it overheating right now? Also, you can just edit the question to add more information. If you indent the block by for *or* surround it with `<pre> </pre>` it will make a code block and line breakes are preserved.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary nVidia drivers? If so, you could check with `nvidia-settings` (may need to be installed) how hot the GPU is.

Comment: Please check the video drivers activated and post them. may be updating them will solve the problem.

Comment: @kashminder this is the problem i guess , and i don't know how to update them , can you help please ?

Comment: @Adaephon u can noticed that it's so hot , how can i know if my drivers are updated ??

Comment: @Ramy I believe you that the laptop as a whole is hot. But the output of `top` indicates that the **C**PU is not really doing anything. Therefore I suspect the **G**PU of being responsible. If the GPU driver fails to clock down the GPU when idle it will runsl at full clock all the time. This may very well lead to chip temperatures over 80 °C. The GPU will not get this hot if the CPU is responsible, so a temperature readout will help localizing the problem.

Comment: @Adaephon what can i do now to solve the problem?